# Javascript and CSS that can replace alerbox. Alert Box is so unprofessional

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom alert using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391864/custom-alert-using-javascript)

I want to create a confirmation message-"Do you want to proceed deleting? [Yes] or [No]".

I have a table with many data rows where the delete link is clicked in a particular row, the data in the row is deleted in the database. When the user clicks the delete option, i want to show the confirmation message first, so that user can validate his actions before deleting.

How can i do that dynamically using java script and css? I don't want to use alerBox() as it is ugly and is so unprofessional.

I am currently working for my school project-jsp and Java Servlet.

Hope any experts will help me. I love this forum as people here are very helpful. Advance thanks!

Comment: More: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+custom+alert

Comment: `alert()` and `confirm()` are unprofessional ? That one is new.

Comment: but for my understanding, alert() will stop the processing thread, not only blocking UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want really to look good try this approach:Use for example jQuery and jQueryUI.

In your page put this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="pathtoyourappfolder/jquery/css/black-tie/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="pathtoyourappfolder/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pathtoyourappfolder/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js'" ></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="dialog-confirm" title="DELETE">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>
    Are you sure you want to delete this record?</p>
  </div>

  <table id="TblName">
    <tr>
        <td class="actions">
            <a href="http://something/somethingelse/1" class="del">del</a>
        </td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="actions">
            <a href="http://something/somethingelse/2" class="del">del</a>
        </td>

        <td></td>
    </tr>   
  </table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#TblName td.actions a.del').click(function(event){
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
        });

 }

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way JavaScript event handling works, there cannot exist any "drop-in" replacement for `confirm`, but popular JavaScript libraries such as jQuery UI include "modal dialog" features that can be used to achieve a similar effect.

http://www.jensbits.com/2009/08/10/modal-confirmation-dialog-on-form-submit-javascript-jquery-ui-and-thickbox-varieties/ is an example of how this works. Your "delete" button would not be set up to submit the form but rather open the modal dialog, which *would* submit the form if the user clicks OK.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could do

```
window.alert = function(text) { /* some code to show a fancy dialog */};
window.confirm = function(question) { /* some code to show a fancy dialog and return the result */}
```

Problem is you're messing around where ought not mess around but the advantage is that even in 3rd party code any alerts() or confirms() will come up as your custom dialogs and the code will be simple to read (instead of $.dialog({options}) you just use a normal alert() or confirm call)

Comment: This would definitely not work because of the way JavaScript handles clicks on buttons on the HTML page ("modal dialog" is irrelevant). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886228/overriding-javascript-confirm-while-preserving-the-callback.

Comment: Confirm would not work since that stops execution of JavaScript and waits for the return value of the conditional. You'd have to supply the code to execute depending on the result as a callback.

Comment: Yeah I forgot that it'd be impossible in javascript. The alert works though

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onclick="deleteRow(row_id, this)"` to each delete link. Usage of `row_id` assumes the table is being generated dynamically from a given set and you have an identifier to provide and pick the data to delete. The `this` is useful to remove the `<tr>` using Javascript.

Oh and of course the function would make a dialog popup. Use jQuery for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try FaceBox and FacyBox

http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/

http://www.bitbonsai.com/facybox/

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the functionality. I am intending you wanna know what's happening and how to achieve effects, instead of using a library like jQuery. jQuery and derived solutions can make your life easier, but if you want to know HOW to make it, continue reading.

First, you should make your own "alertBox", with your preferred CSS styling (including it's position) [I suggest position absolute, z-index:2], then in the CSS let its display property as hidden.

OK, now when user clicks your delete link/button you trigger a native javascript confirm dialog. Replace this confirm call, to a function that will display your own styled menu. changing its CSS display property from hidden to "block".

On your own styled menu buttons Yes/No, attach events, one for each button, with respective action (hide menu, or deleting row, removing current line from table...).

Well, that's the idea. Hope you enjoy.